# ApplicationInsightDataClient GetCustomEventWithHttpMessageAsync not loading custom dimension

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights 0.9.0 -preview version to get custom events from application insights

```
    public async Task<ApplicationInsightsFooDto[]> Foo(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var activeDirectoryServiceSettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
        {
            AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com"),
            TokenAudience = new Uri("https://api.applicationinsights.io/"),
            ValidateAuthority = true
        };

        ServiceClientCredentials serviceCredentials = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(
            domain: ApplicationInsightConstants.DirectoryId,
            clientId: ApplicationInsightConstants.ClientId,
            secret: ApplicationInsightConstants.ClientSecret,
            settings: activeDirectoryServiceSettings
        ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var applicationInsightsDataClient = new ApplicationInsightsDataClient(serviceCredentials)
        {
            AppId = ApplicationInsightConstants.AppId,
        };
        applicationInsightsDataClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", "<myApiKey>");

        var myEvents = await applicationInsightsDataClient.GetCustomEventsWithHttpMessagesAsync(search: "LoginEvent", timespan: timeSpan);

        return new ApplicationInsightsFooDto[] { };
    }
```

The response current does not include CustomDimension as shown in image below:

[image]

However if I directly make an api call I get customDimensions

Example request:

```
GET https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<myAppId>/events/customEvents?$search=LoginEvent&timespan=PT1H HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
X-Api-Key: <myApiKey>
```

Example response:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/<myappId>/events/$metadata#customEvents",
"@ai.messages":[{"code":"AddedLimitToQuery","message":"The query was limited to 500 rows"}],"value": 
[{"id":"...","count":1,"type":"customEvent","timestamp":"...",
"customEvent":{"name":"LoginEvent"},
"customDimensions":{"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","DeveloperMode":"true","UserId":"...","...":"...","UserName":"Xyz","...":"...","Company":"N/A"},"customMeasurements":null,"operation":{"name":"POST Account/Login","id":"someData","p","syntheticSource":""},...}}]}
```

Host: api.applicationinsights.io

Any idea how I can fetch customDimension using C# sdk rather than building custom url and then making a request?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I ended up doing

```
 var myEvents = await applicationInsightsDataClient
                .QueryWithHttpMessagesAsync(
                    "customEvents " +
                    "| where name == \"LoginEvent\"" +
                    "| project customDimensions ");
```

apparently calling `QueryWithHttpMessageAsync` works

Answer (score 1):

This works and contains all the data, you'll just have to handle some type detection and deserialization manually.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;

namespace AIClient
{
    class Program
    {
        const string SEARCH_TEXT = "some text";

        // See AppInsights API Access
        const string APP_INSIGHTS_APP_ID = "........-....-....-....-............";

        // AAD app auth
        const string CLIENT_ID = "........-....-....-....-............";
        const string CLIENT_SECRET = ".................";
        const string DOMAIN = "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com";
        const string AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
        const string TOKEN_AUDIENCE = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

            ApplicationInsightsDataClient client = await GetClientAsync();

            HttpOperationResponse<QueryResults> traces = await SearchAsync(client, SEARCH_TEXT);

            //Print(traces);
        }

        private static async Task<ApplicationInsightsDataClient> GetClientAsync()
        {
            ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings adSettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
            {
                AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri(AUTH_ENDPOINT),
                TokenAudience = new Uri(TOKEN_AUDIENCE),
                ValidateAuthority = true
            };

            // Authenticate with client secret (app key)
            ServiceClientCredentials credentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(DOMAIN, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, adSettings);

            // New up a client with credentials and AI application Id
            ApplicationInsightsDataClient client = new ApplicationInsightsDataClient(credentials) { AppId = APP_INSIGHTS_APP_ID };

            return client;
        }

        private static async Task<HttpOperationResponse<QueryResults>> SearchAsync(ApplicationInsightsDataClient client, string text)
        {
            HttpOperationResponse<QueryResults> traces = await client.QueryWithHttpMessagesAsync(
                query: "search '" + text + "' | order by timestamp asc",
                timespan: TimeSpan.FromHours(48));

            return traces;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been reported to the product team. For now the recommended course of action is to use the API endpoint directly if you need that property.